# Get a single row from mysqli_query output using a parameter, without loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to get a single row from mysqli_query result out of the array of rows { got from mysqli_fetch_array('result_from_mysqli_query'>) } based on a value of a particular column, without the help of loop?

I am new to PHP, please let me know if there is a function for this? I am working on improving a application written in PHP which is having a complex query that is taking >500 Seconds to execute. The query is like this:

```
SELECT distinct(t1.`testName`) AS test1, t1.`className`, t1.`duration`, t1.`id`, t1.`skipped`, t1.`failedSince`, t1.`buildNumber`, t1.`errorStackTrace`, t2.`errorStackTrace` AS E2, t3.`errorStackTrace` AS E3, t4.`errorStackTrace` AS E4, t5.`tester`, t1.`comments`, t2.`comments` AS C2, t2.`buildNumber` AS B2, t3.`comments` AS C3, t3.`buildNumber` AS B3, t4.`comments` AS C4, t4.`buildNumber` as B4, t5.`tester` AS owner, t5.`jira_id`, t6.`occurences`
from
`sample` AS t1
left join `testnametester` as t5 ON t1.`testName` = t5.`testCase`
left join `statsbuilder` as t6 on t1.`testName`= t6.`testName`
left join `sample` as t2 on t1.`testName` = t2.`testName`
left join `sample` as t3 on t1.`testName` = t3.`testName`
left join `sample` as t4 on t1.`testName` = t4.`testName`
where t1.`buildNumber`=500 and t1.`errorStackTrace` IS NOT NULL and t2.`buildNumber`=499 and t3.`buildNumber`=498 and t4.`buildNumber`=497 group by t1.id order by t1.testName desc
```

Now, to make this query faster I am trying to execute the query for t2, t3 & t4 separately and take only that row from these query results that is matching with result of t1 (based on testname) one by one, and use it in printing a table of data. Now, if I use a loop to get the data from t2/t3/t4 results that is matching with testName of t1 then the complexity will somewhat remain same.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's probably a good idea to try and optimize your query. MySQL is usally way better at optimizing itself than you are.

Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html for some explanation. Basically, putting `EXPLAIN` in front of your query, MySQL will show you some info about how the query is run - which indexes are used etc. You should add indexes on the proper columns if you want fast queries - have you done that?

Secondly, why are you executing 4 (join) queries? Can't you just write `WHERE t1.buildNumber >= 497 AND t1.buildNumber <= 500`?

For example:

```sql
SELECT distinct(t1.`testName`) AS test1,
       t1.`className`,
       t1.`duration`,
       t1.`id`,
       t1.`skipped`,
       t1.`failedSince`,
       t1.`buildNumber`,
       t1.`errorStackTrace`,
       t1.`comments`,

       -- t5.`tester`, we can remove this one as you're selecting it twice
       t5.`tester` AS OWNER,
       t5.`jira_id`,
       t6.`occurences`,
FROM `sample` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `testnametester` AS t5 ON t1.`testName` = t5.`testCase`
LEFT JOIN `statsbuilder` AS t6 ON t1.`testName`= t6.`testName`
WHERE `t1`.`buildNumber` >= 497
  AND `t1`.`buildNumber` <= 500
  AND `t1`.`errorStackTrace` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.testName DESC
```

Comment: I need particular column(s) data (errorStackTrace, comments etc.) for last three buildNumbers as well that's why I am using 4 join queries.

Comment: But your join on clauses are the same, so they should match the same rows in the sample table. You'll just get extra copies of those columns. Part of the problem is that conditions that should be part of the on clauses are in the where.

Comment: As far as I understood problem will remain same, I need to show errorStackTrace, Comments for a particular testname in a same html table row for 4 builds (t1, t2, t3, t4). Then to get these columns from the output of this query, I have to query again on buildNumber.

Comment: Technically the query without the joins should to the same as the one with the joins, but the one without should be much faster. Can you try and see if you get the results you need? Because with the joins included, you are practically executing 4 different queries.